# differentiating species groups using different colors in a NMDS plot (R)

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to figure out how can I differentiate species groups in a NMDS plot ("vegan" package).

I tried this code:

```
points(ord, display = "species",col=ifelse("Hylocomiastrum umbratum"|"Scapania apiculata"|"Neckera pennata"|"Crossocalyx hellerianus"|"Syzygiella autumnalis"|"Lepidozia reptans"|"Nowellia curvifolia"|"Riccardia latifrons"|"Riccardia palmata"|"Trichocolea tomentella"|"Ulota crispa"==TRUE,"red","black"), pch="*", cex=0.9)
```

I wanted to display some species with red symbols and others in black. The code works just fine unless I try to change colors.

Received this messeage:

> Error in "Hylocomiastrum umbratum" | "Scapania apiculata" :
> operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Can someone please help out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
species_of_interest <- c("Hylocomiastrum umbratum", "Scapania apiculata", "Neckera pennata", "Crossocalyx hellerianus", "Syzygiella autumnalis", "Lepidozia reptans", "Nowellia curvifolia", "Riccardia latifrons", "Riccardia palmata", "Trichocolea tomentella", "Ulota crispa")

points(ord, display = "species", 
       col = ifelse(row.names(ord$Species) %in% species_of_interest, "red", "black"), 
       pch = "*", cex = 0.9)
```

The | operator works with logical vectors, not with character vectors.

Comment: Thank you so much, with a minor change (had to specify row.names(ord) ->  row.names (ord$species)) it worked!! So grateful, all the best to you!

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered if you're happy.  All the best.